# PySimpleGUI align sg.radio buttons vertically?

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Is there a way to have a sg.radio button display it's buttons vertically instead of horizontally? Ideally I'd like to have 5 columns of 5 buttons, with the options for each displaying beneath each other.

Comment: Any figure to show what layout it looks like ?

Comment: Not sure without a picture exactly what's meant, but if you mean the circle and then put the text directly under it, you could use a blank text value for the Radio element and place a Text element on the next row that has the Text for the radio button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon the same problem.
It is probably related to the use of square brackets (one pair `[]` per line), compare `col1` and `col2`:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('SystemDefaultForReal')

col1 = [[sg.Text('Vertical')],
        [sg.Radio('A', 'group 1', key='VA', enable_events=True)],
        [sg.Radio('B', 'group 1', key='VB', enable_events=True)]
        ]

col2 = [[sg.Text('Horizontal'),
         sg.Radio('A', 'group 2', key='HA', enable_events=True),
         sg.Radio('B', 'group 2', key='HB' , enable_events=True)
         ]]

layout = [[sg.Column(col1), sg.VSeparator(), sg.Column(col2)]]

window =sg.Window('Columns', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True)
while True:  # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```